# How to create conditional constraint for two binary variables?

Tags: limits, discrete-mathematics, binary-programming

I need to include the following conditional constraint in my MIP formulation. I have the following situation in a Mixed Integer Program: A1,…,An and B
are binary variables. If two or more variables $A_i$ are set to $1$, then I need to have $B=1$.

That is:    $$\sum_{i=1}^n A_i \geq2 \Longrightarrow B=1$$

Do I need to introduce a new variable here?
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with one "big-M" constraint as follows:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n A_i - 1 \le (n-1)B.$$

Alternatively, you can obtain $\binom{n}{2}$ linear constraints via conjunctive normal form:
\begin{equation}
\bigvee_{i<j} \left(A_i \land A_j\right) \implies B \\
\neg\bigvee_{i<j} (A_i \land A_j) \lor B \\
\bigwedge_{i<j} \neg(A_i \land A_j) \lor B \\
\bigwedge_{i<j} (\neg A_i \lor \neg A_j) \lor B \\
\bigwedge_{i<j} (\neg A_i \lor \neg A_j \lor B) \\
1- A_i + 1- A_j + B \ge 1 \text{ for all $i<j$} \\
A_i + A_j - 1 \le B \text{ for all $i<j$}
\end{equation}